# \marks with two column output

Tags: header-footer, two-column, multicol, mark

I'm trying to understand how `\marks`, `\firstmarks`, and `\botmarks` works with two column output.

In the following MWE, the headers work as I want with one column output. The right mark is the last verse on page 1 and the left mark is the first verse on page 2.

But when I introduce two columns (either with the `multicols` package or with the `twocolumn` class option) things go wrong.

There are two issues with pages 3 and 4:

1. The header on page 3 should be *John 1:12*, not *John 1:13* to match the last verse on the page. (This error seems to occur only with the `multicols` package, not with the `twocolumn` class option.)
2. The header on page 4 should be *John 1:13*, not *John 1:18* to match the first verse on the page. (This error occurs with both the `multicols` package and the `twocolumn` class option.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\newmarks\versemark

\def\leftmark{\firstmarks\versemark}
\def\rightmark{\botmarks\versemark}

\newcommand*{\vs}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{#1}%
  \marks\versemark{John 1:#1}%
}

\hyphenation{dwell-ing}

\newcommand{\prologue}{%
  \vs{1}In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
  was God. \vs{2}He was with God in the beginning. \vs{3}Through him all
  things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made. \vs{4}In
  him was life, and that life was the light of all mankind. \vs{5}The light
  shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.

  \vs{6}There was a man sent from God whose name was John. \vs{7}He came as a
  witness to testify concerning that light, so that through him all might
  believe. \vs{8}He himself was not the light; he came only as a witness to
  the light.

  \vs{9}The true light that gives light to everyone was coming into the world.
  \vs{10}He was in the world, and though the world was made through him, the
  world did not recognise him. \vs{11}He came to that which was his own, but
  his own did not receive him. \vs{12}Yet to all who did receive him, to those
  who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of
  God---\vs{13}children born not of natural descent, nor of human decision or
  a husband’s will, but born of God.

  \vs{14}The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen
  his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full
  of grace and truth.

  \vs{15}(John testified concerning him. He cried out, saying, ‘This is the
  one I spoke about when I said, “He who comes after me has surpassed me
  because he was before me.”\,’) \vs{16}Out of his fullness we have all
  received grace in place of grace already given. \vs{17}For the law was given
  through Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ. \vs{18}No one has
  ever seen God, but the one and only Son, who is himself God and is in the
  closest relationship with the Father, has made him known.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \huge John
\end{center}
\prologue
\clearpage
\begin{center}
  \huge John
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \prologue
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multicol and twocolumn call the output routine more than once, and this changes the marks. You should better stick to the standard latex mark commands, as both the kernel and multicol contain code to reset them correctly in such cases (search e.g. multicol for `keptmarks`).

This document shows the difference between your marks and the standard \left/\rightmark:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\tiny fv: \firstversemark, bv: \botversemark, lm: \leftmark, rm: \rightmark}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}


\newmarks\versemark

\def\firstversemark{\firstmarks\versemark}
\def\botversemark{\botmarks\versemark}

\newcommand*{\vs}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{#1}%
  \marks\versemark{John 1:#1}%
  \markboth{John 1:#1}{John 1:#1}%
}

\hyphenation{dwell-ing}

\newcommand{\prologue}{%
  \vs{1}In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
  was God. \vs{2}He was with God in the beginning. \vs{3}Through him all
  things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made. \vs{4}In
  him was life, and that life was the light of all mankind. \vs{5}The light
  shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.

  \vs{6}There was a man sent from God whose name was John. \vs{7}He came as a
  witness to testify concerning that light, so that through him all might
  believe. \vs{8}He himself was not the light; he came only as a witness to
  the light.

  \vs{9}The true light that gives light to everyone was coming into the world.
  \vs{10}He was in the world, and though the world was made through him, the
  world did not recognise him. \vs{11}He came to that which was his own, but
  his own did not receive him. \vs{12}Yet to all who did receive him, to those
  who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of
  God---\vs{13}children born not of natural descent, nor of human decision or
  a husband’s will, but born of God.

  \vs{14}The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen
  his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full
  of grace and truth.

  \vs{15}(John testified concerning him. He cried out, saying, ‘This is the
  one I spoke about when I said, “He who comes after me has surpassed me
  because he was before me.”\,’) \vs{16}Out of his fullness we have all
  received grace in place of grace already given. \vs{17}For the law was given
  through Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ. \vs{18}No one has
  ever seen God, but the one and only Son, who is himself God and is in the
  closest relationship with the Father, has made him known.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \huge John
\end{center}
\prologue
\clearpage
\begin{center}
  \huge John
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \prologue
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to get the left and right mark the wrong way round though. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The \leftmark is the left part from the last markboth,  \rightmark the right part of the first markboth. I used the same text in both \markboth arguments, but one could do more complicated stuff (and also use \markright).

Comment: But isn't this the whole point of `\marks` and `\firstmarks` and `\botmarks`? But I gather your answer is just saying, you can't do this (with two columns), so write the logic yourself using `\markboth`. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean. But yes, you can't use the primitives (neither \marks nor the standard \mark) directly. You could look at xmarks(2): https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/xmarks/l3trial/xmarks.

Comment: I think I don't understand marks :(. I want to set the header on odd pages to the last verse. I had hoped that `\botmark` (or `\botmarks`) would do this. (And it seems to with one column—and I'm happy with your explanation that I can't use the primitives for two columns.) But `\rightmark` always holds the first verse from the page, so I don't see how I can call `\markboth` or `\markright` unless I know in advance what the last verse of the page is… The analogous output with `\section` commands would be to have have 2 sections on page 1 and the second (not first) one to be in the header.

Comment: What is wrong with \leftmark for the last verse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87592/discussion-between-david-purton-and-ulrike-fischer).